# Масштабирование элементов Panel в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть форма, панель на ней, и в панеле элементы. Я хочу при изменении размера формы масштабировать размеры элементов панели так, чтобы они не вылазили за поля формы. Пытался с помощью Dock и Anchor, но при уменьшении элементы вылазят за пределы панели и вообще окна. Как сделать автоматическое масштабирование элементов в панеле?

Comment: TableLayoutPanel пробовали? Какое поведение ожидается, когда дальнейшее изменение размеров элементов невозможно и они не влезают в доступную область? Для особо изощренных случаев можно подписаться на событие изменения размера и масштабировать ручками, но это на самый крайний случай.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1351937/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0 -Здесь я решил такую проблему