# Как сделать так, что бы элементы масштабировались, при увеличении окна

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сделать так что бы при увеличении окна, элементы масштабировались и оставались на своих местах. С помощью Anchor элементы расставил как надо, но они не увеличиваются. Погуглил, ничего конкретного про масштабируемость не нашел кроме метода Scale. Как его использовать не понимаю. Подскажите как "малой кровью" увеличивать элементы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код дизайнера

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">истинно, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; иначе ложно.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.flowLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.flowLayoutPanel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.pictureBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.flowLayoutPanel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.pictureBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.flowLayoutPanel4 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.pictureBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.flowLayoutPanel5 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.pictureBox5 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.flowLayoutPanel6 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.pictureBox6 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).BeginInit();
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).BeginInit();
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox4)).BeginInit();
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox5)).BeginInit();
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox6)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.pictureBox1.Image = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.заметки;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 180);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 186);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 6;
            this.label1.Text = "label1";
            // 
            // flowLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52, 54);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 7;
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 3;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel6, 2, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel5, 1, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel4, 0, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel3, 2, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel2, 1, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel1, 0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.FixedSize;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(872, 622);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // flowLayoutPanel2
            // 
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.AutoSize = true;
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox2);
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(342, 54);
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.Name = "flowLayoutPanel2";
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // pictureBox2
            // 
            this.pictureBox2.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.pictureBox2.Image = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.заметки;
            this.pictureBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.pictureBox2.Name = "pictureBox2";
            this.pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 180);
            this.pictureBox2.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox2.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox2.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 186);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 6;
            this.label2.Text = "label2";
            // 
            // flowLayoutPanel3
            // 
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.AutoSize = true;
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox3);
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(633, 54);
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.Name = "flowLayoutPanel3";
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.TabIndex = 9;
            // 
            // pictureBox3
            // 
            this.pictureBox3.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.pictureBox3.Image = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.заметки;
            this.pictureBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.pictureBox3.Name = "pictureBox3";
            this.pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 180);
            this.pictureBox3.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox3.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox3.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 186);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 6;
            this.label3.Text = "label3";
            // 
            // flowLayoutPanel4
            // 
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.AutoSize = true;
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox4);
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.label4);
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52, 365);
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.Name = "flowLayoutPanel4";
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.TabIndex = 10;
            // 
            // pictureBox4
            // 
            this.pictureBox4.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.pictureBox4.Image = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.заметки;
            this.pictureBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.pictureBox4.Name = "pictureBox4";
            this.pictureBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 180);
            this.pictureBox4.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox4.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox4.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this.label4.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label4.AutoSize = true;
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 186);
            this.label4.Name = "label4";
            this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
            this.label4.TabIndex = 6;
            this.label4.Text = "label4";
            // 
            // flowLayoutPanel5
            // 
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.AutoSize = true;
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox5);
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(this.label5);
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(342, 365);
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.Name = "flowLayoutPanel5";
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.TabIndex = 11;
            // 
            // pictureBox5
            // 
            this.pictureBox5.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.pictureBox5.Image = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.заметки;
            this.pictureBox5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.pictureBox5.Name = "pictureBox5";
            this.pictureBox5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 180);
            this.pictureBox5.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox5.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox5.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this.label5.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label5.AutoSize = true;
            this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 186);
            this.label5.Name = "label5";
            this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
            this.label5.TabIndex = 6;
            this.label5.Text = "label5";
            // 
            // flowLayoutPanel6
            // 
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.AutoSize = true;
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox6);
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.Controls.Add(this.label6);
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(633, 365);
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.Name = "flowLayoutPanel6";
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 203);
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.TabIndex = 12;
            // 
            // pictureBox6
            // 
            this.pictureBox6.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom;
            this.pictureBox6.Image = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.заметки;
            this.pictureBox6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.pictureBox6.Name = "pictureBox6";
            this.pictureBox6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 180);
            this.pictureBox6.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox6.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox6.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this.label6.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom;
            this.label6.AutoSize = true;
            this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 186);
            this.label6.Name = "label6";
            this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
            this.label6.TabIndex = 6;
            this.label6.Text = "label6";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(872, 622);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.flowLayoutPanel2.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).EndInit();
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.flowLayoutPanel3.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).EndInit();
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.flowLayoutPanel4.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox4)).EndInit();
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.flowLayoutPanel5.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox5)).EndInit();
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.flowLayoutPanel6.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox6)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не уверен, что в winforms такое в принципе возможно. В смысле, вручную можно что угодно написать, но из-коробки такой функции нет. Либо я не понял вопроса и нужен конкретный пример.

Comment: вероятнее всего человеку нужен какой-то грид из wpf. Но на винформс)))

Comment: @Andrew нет ничего невозможного, но вопрос слишком общий, совершенно непонятно, что автору нужно. Плюс запрос странный, никто не зумит содержимое формы просто так, это может сломать соотношение сторон контролов и сплющить интерфейс либо по вертикали, либо по горизонтали.

Comment: @aepot, добавил скрины, код я не написал...

Comment: Так начните писать. Поизучайте `TableLayoutPanel` и `FlowLayoutPanel` и зачем они нужны. Научитесь задавать размеры контролам не в пикселях, а чтобы они ресайзились в зависимости от выделенной им области (AutoSize).

Comment: @aepot, Благодарю за наводку

Comment: @aepot, сделал через TableLayoutPanel и FlowLayoutPanel, все отцентрировал,  но картинки не увеличиваются

Comment: Картинки в пикчербоксах, или сами пикчербоксы? Покажите код.

Comment: Я их создавал статически, при помощи перетаскивания, для теста, чтоб понять как это работает

Comment: `this.pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 180);` размер пикчербокса задан в пикселях, фиксированный. С чего вы взяли, что она должна изменять свой размер просто так?

Comment: @aepot, написал, this.pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(tableLayoutPanel1.Width, tableLayoutPanel1.Height); И указал MaximumSize. Это костыли? Или ты это и имел в виду?

Comment: AutoSize же есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось куда проще, моя ошибка была в том, что я использовал в TableLayoutPanel FlowLayoutPanel. Помог также запрос "Все что вы хотели узнать о TableLayoutPanel, но боялись спросить". Надеюсь что кому то поможет.

Теперь все работает так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#region Создаю TableLayoutPanel 
                this.Controls.Clear();
                TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel
                {
                    AutoSize = true,
                    CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.InsetDouble,
                    ColumnCount = 3,
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.FixedSize,
                    Location = new Point(0, 0),
                    RowCount = 2
                };
                this.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);
                tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
                tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
                tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
    
                tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
                tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
                #endregion
    
                Panel panel1 = new Panel
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    AutoSize = true,
                    MinimumSize = new Size(180, 180),
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                };
                tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(panel1, 0, 0);
                PictureBox pic1 = new PictureBox
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    Image = Properties.Resources.картинка,
                    MinimumSize = new Size(160, 160),
                    MaximumSize = new Size(350, 350),
                    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                };
                panel1.Controls.Add(pic1);
                Panel panel11 = new Panel
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                    AutoSize = true,
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                };
                panel1.Controls.Add(panel11);
                Label lab1 = new Label
                {
                    AutoSize = false,
                    Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                    Text = "Просто текст",
                    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                };
                panel11.Controls.Add(lab1);
```